# MongoDB + Node.js - Password Can Not Be Empty when Adding new Admin User

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to secure my MongoDB install. I get this error when I try to add my first Admin.

```
root@server:/# mongo auth
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: auth 
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.addUser( { user: "supermongo", pwd: "superpassword", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } )
Sat Mar 15 11:47:57 uncaught exception: password can't be empty
>
```

`--version`

```
root@server:/# mongos --version
MongoS version 2.2.3 starting: pid=12720 port=27017 64-bit host=server (--help for usage)
git version: f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08
build sys info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
root@server:/# mongod --version
db version v2.2.3, pdfile version 4.5
Sat Mar 15 11:47:29 git version: f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08
root@server:/# mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
```

Comment: upgrade to 2.4, and try again

Comment: I flipped to the 2.2 documentation and it worked. apt-get was getting stubborn and 2.2 was all it could find. http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2//